# pg_dump and pg_restore: input file does not appear to be a valid archive

Tags: postgresql, database-restore, pg-dump

I have used pg_dump on one machine and copied result file to another, where I tried to restore it. I believe schema is the same. However, I get:

> pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive

I have done following operations:

```
pg_dump -a -f db.txt dbname
```

And:

```
pg_restore -a -d dbname db.txt
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: Try importing the dump on the same machine that generated it. Also, check the Postgres versions.

Comment: I can't try importing it on the same machine, because it's a production machine. Any idea, what else I can do?

Comment: This solution may also be relevant to some people: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433414/heroku-database-restore-issue/42435490#42435490

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You are dumping in plain SQL format which was designed to feed to `psql`. This is not recognized by `pg_restore`.

```
cat db.txt | psql dbname
```

Should do the trick

Comment: or `psql dbname < db.txt` ;)

Comment: it also requires username in windows machine : "cat dump_file | psql db_user"

Answer (score 37):

`pg_dump` by default creates the sql commmands necessary to recreate the data. To recover it, you just need to invoke `psql` (not `pg_restore` ) with the file as input . `pg_restore` is only to be used for the binary (not default, and less usual <s>not recommended</s>) format of `pg_dump`. Read the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE).

Update: The `pg_dump` binary formats (`-Fc` `-Ft`) that are to be used with `pg_restore` are ok, and offer some extra flexibility. But they are less standard (non SQL), less apt for importing from some tools (eg. a php frontend) or manipulate with a text editor, and a little less portable to other versions and even other databases. For backups, I'd stick with the default plain format. For other scenarios, the binary + pg_restore option can be equally or more apt.

The point to keep is that in Postgresql, in the **typical scenario**, the backup normally is done by **pg_dump** (plain) and the restore with the standard command line client (**psql**).

Comment: [OT] I beg to differ regarding the "not recommended" status of the custom output format - the sentence "This is the most flexible format in that it allows reordering of loading data as well as object definitions..." from the manual seems to me as quite an endorsement.

Comment: "not recommended" was an overstatement, I agree. But "most flexible" does not necessarily means "most recommended". Clarified.

Answer (score 18):

Try passing the `--format=c` option to `pg_dump`. This will allow `pg_restore` to restore it.

Comment: Would whoever modded this down like to explain why? The accepted answer explains that this will work :-)

Comment: @skrafi: What is your point?

Comment: sorry, copy-pasted wrong output, the right one is `pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header` so this doesn't work for simple sql dump

Comment: @skrafi: I'm not sure what you mean. If you use `pg_dump --format=c ...> archivefile`, and then use `pg_restore` on `archivefile`, then (at least when I tested it just now) it works fine. Maybe your file is corrupt somehow? Or you have hit a particular bug?

Answer (score 10):

This is what I would do to backup my old database and restore

To back up your database

```
pg_dump --format=c olddb_name > db_dump_file.dump
```

To restore that backup

```
pg_restore -v -d newdb_name db_dump_file.dump
```

Read more on [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgdump.html) and [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgrestore.html)

Answer (score 6):

For windows users try

```
type db.txt | psql --username="YOURNAME" dbname
```

Works like a charm

Comment: This saved me thank you! Should be accepted answer for windows at least.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something to MySQL's `SOURCE` command:

```
psql dbname
```

Then, in postgresql terminal:

```
\i filename
```

Answer (score 2):

```bash
cat dumpFileName | psql -h ip -d dbName -U userName -W
```

Comment: It's usually helpful if you explain what that does and why it might help.

Answer (score 1):

This error message could also mean that there's actually something wrong with the backup file (or your assumptions about it).

In one case, I had mounted a backup file in a Docker container and tried to restore, but it failed with `does not appear to be a valid archive`. And in fact, the file was empty, because the mount was not performed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, call the `psql` client of Postgres, in the shell, with the parameters as below:

```
psql -h <your_host_name> -p <postgres_port_number> -U <your_user_name_in_postgres> -f "<your_sql_script>.sql" <your_database_name>
```

Example:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -f "C:\Users\Mx\Downloads\northwind.postgre.sql" northwind
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive

Because I exported but did not archive `apple` database to `backup.sql` with [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) as shown below:

```
pg_dump -U john apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump -U john -Fp apple > backup.sql
```

Then, I tried to import non-archive `backup.sql` to `orange` database with [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) which must be used to import archive files:

```
pg_restore -U john -d orange < backup.sql
```

So, I did it with [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) which must be used to import non-archive files, then I could solve the error. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984733/postgresql-export-database-to-sql-file/77251389#77251389) explains how to export schema and data and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line/77275771#77275771) explains how to import schema and data:

```
psql -U john -f backup.sql orange
```