# Loading a big database dump into PostgreSQL using cat

Tags: memory, postgresql, cat

I have a pair of very large (~17 GB) database dumps that I want to load into postgresql 9.3. After installing the database packages, learning more or less how to use them, and fiddling around a little on various StackExchange pages (particularly [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/260607/pg-dump-and-pg-restore-input-file-does-not-appear-to-be-a-valid-archive)), it looks like a proper command for me to use is something like:

```
cat mydb.pgdump | psql mydb
```

because of the format the dump is in. My machine has 16 GB of RAM, and I'm not familiar with the `cat` command but I do know that my RAM is 99% exhausted and the database is taking a while to load. My machine isn't non-responsive to the point of hanging; I can run other commands in other terminal windows and have them execute at a reasonable clip, but I am wondering if `cat` is the best way to pipe in the file or if something else is more efficient? My concern is that maybe `cat` could be using up all the RAM so the database doesn't have much to work with, throttling its performance. But I'm new to thinking about RAM issues like this and don't know if I'm worrying about nothing.

Now that I think about it, this seems to be more of a question about `cat` and its memory usage than anything else. If there is a more appropriate forum for this question please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: The correct load command is `psql dbname < infile` ([documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE))

Comment: Additionally, there is [documentation about large database dumps here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-LARGE) They recommend using the `split` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My concern is that maybe cat could be using up all the RAM so the database doesn't have much to work with, throttling its performance.

It isn't. `cat` just streams data from input to output.

It's unnecessary here anyway, use

```
psql dbname < mydb.pgdump
```

> my RAM is 99% exhausted and the database is taking a while to load.

How are you measuring "99% exhaused"? I'm wondering if you're failing to exclude buffers/cache. Show the output of `free -h` (or if that fails with an error, `free -m`).

In general, for a faster DB restore I recommend taking a custom-format (`-Fc`) dump then using parallel `pg_restore` instead of `psql`.